# Check if multiple packages in redhat machine are already installed if not available then install via ansible playbook

Tags: variables, installation, ansible, conditional-statements

> I want to check if certain packages are installed in my nodes or not.
> If not then install those packages via ansible playbook.

Here are the variables that I am providing to the playbook as input (node IPs & packages to be installed):

```yaml
exec_server: '10.50.10.40,34.228.208.5'
pkgs:
  - zip
  - unzip
  - git
```

Here is the playbook I wrote to find out if any of the packages has been installed and, if not, then install them.

```yaml
- name: Check Package installation
  hosts: "{{ exec_server }}"
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - name: Gather the packager facts
      package_facts:
        manager: "auto"
  
    - name: Package status
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} {{ 'installed' if item in ansible_facts.packages else 'not installed' }}"
      loop: "{{ pkgs | default([]) }}"
      register: find_output

    - name: install the latest version of not installed Packages
      yum:
        name: "{% if pkgs is undefined in ansible_facts.packages %}-{{ pkgs }}{% endif %}"
        state: latest
```

The error that I am facing:

```
Identity added: /tmp/awx_2137_f_94gy2c/artifacts/2137/ssh_key_data (/tmp/awx_2137_f_94gy2c/artifacts/2137/ssh_key_data)

PLAY [Check Package installation] **********************************************

TASK [Gather the packager facts] ***********************************************
ok: [34.228.208.5]
ok: [10.50.10.40]

TASK [Package status] **********************************************************
ok: [10.50.10.40] => (item=zip) => {
    "msg": "zip installed"
}
ok: [10.50.10.40] => (item=unzip) => {
    "msg": "unzip installed"
}
ok: [10.50.10.40] => (item=git) => {
    "msg": "git not installed"
}
ok: [10.50.10.40] => (item=python-pip) => {
    "msg": "python-pip not installed"
}
ok: [10.50.10.40] => (item=gcc) => {
    "msg": "gcc not installed"
}
ok: [34.228.208.5] => (item=zip) => {
    "msg": "zip installed"
}
ok: [34.228.208.5] => (item=unzip) => {
    "msg": "unzip installed"
}
ok: [34.228.208.5] => (item=git) => {
    "msg": "git not installed"
}
ok: [34.228.208.5] => (item=python-pip) => {
    "msg": "python-pip not installed"
}
ok: [34.228.208.5] => (item=gcc) => {
    "msg": "gcc not installed"
}

TASK [install the latest version of Uninstalled Packages] **********************
fatal: [10.50.10.40]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'ansible_facts'. String: {% if pkgs is undefined in ansible_facts.packages %}-{{ pkgs }}{% endif %}"}
fatal: [34.228.208.5]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'ansible_facts'. String: {% if pkgs is undefined in ansible_facts.packages %}-{{ pkgs }}{% endif %}"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
10.50.10.40                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
34.228.208.5               : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

How can I only get the packages that are not installed based on my `pkgs` variables and the facts gathered by Ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to check if the package is installed or not before doing anything, this is what the `state: present` is for:

> `present` and `installed` will simply ensure that a desired package is installed.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#parameter-state*</sup>

So your playbook should be as simple as

```yaml
- name: Check Package installation
  hosts: "{{ exec_server }}"
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - name: install the latest version of not installed Packages
      yum:
        name: "{{ pkgs }}"
        state: present
```

---

Now if you want to know what is incorrect in your construct, it is the `if`:

```
{% if pkgs is undefined in ansible_facts.packages %}-{{ pkgs }}{% endif %}
```

You cannot run two test on the same variable in the same instruction (without an `or` or `and`, that is).
While here you are trying to run an [`in`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#in) and [`is undefined`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#undefined) tests at the same time.

What you could do, if you want to keep in that route, which is sub-optimal, as stated above, is to use the [`difference`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory) filter:

```yaml
- name: install the latest version of not installed Packages
  yum:
    name: "{{ pkgs | difference(ansible_facts.packages) }}"
    state: latest
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :). I tried the above and all the packages were got installed except python-pip. Do we need to mention any other module to install python-pip ?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1519803?

Comment: $ pip -V
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
This is what i see when i checking if pip installed or not

But when i was checking the same via playbook , it was showing 
}
ok: [34.228.208.5] => (item=python-pip) => {
    "msg": "python-pip not installed"
}

Comment: Well, that just means that pip was not installed via a rpm package, not that it is not installed at all.

Comment: What does `yum list installed | grep pip` gives you?

Comment: libpipeline.x86_64                    1.2.3-3.el7                     anaconda
python2-pip.noarch                    8.1.2-14.el7                    epel
python3-pip.noarch                    9.0.3-8.el7                     base

Comment: So that answers your question. you do have a package `python3-pip` and a package `python2-pip` install, but I guess `python-pip` is not a thing. Based on what python you want to use (2.x, not recommended, as it is out of support, or 3.x), you should install the correspondant `python[2|3]-pip` version, and so update your `pkgs` list accordingly